# Does Contextual switching Boost Motivation?

Tags: motivation, cognitive

Does contextual switching (or its derivatives thereof such as multitasking) increase one's motivation to further continue with the original activity?

An example: I see people at the gym who listen to music while on the treadmill, or even in the library while solving math problems. They claim that it motivates them. Are they correct?

Comment: Hi Dimyak, welcome at cogsci and thank you for your question. Could you provide us with a bit more context about your question. What is contextual switching for instance? Moreover, I advice you to narrow your post down to one question. This way it is more likely you'll receive a satisfying and then you can ask a follow up question if anything was left unanswered.